# Text overflowing flexbox item

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to have a float element and two lines of text on the right side of it (I dont want these two lines to break in any way). I also need the container to be a flex item.

This below example is wrong as text2 breaks and goes under the float element:

```
 .container1 {
      display: flex;
    }

    .float {
      float: left;
      height: 30px;
      width: 30px;
      background-color: brown;
    }

    .text1 {
      background-color: green;
    }

    .text2 {
      background-color: tomato;
    }
```

```
 <div class="container1">
    <div class="container2">
      <div class="float"></div>
      <div class="text1">Text1 </div>
      <div class="text2">Text2 and some other</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Using `white-space: nowrap;` fixes the breaking issue but then the text overflows:

```
.container1 {
      display: flex;
    }

    .container2 {

      white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .float {
      float: left;
      height: 30px;
      width: 30px;
      background-color: brown;
    }

    .text1 {
      background-color: green;
    }

    .text2 {
      background-color: tomato;
    }
```

```
<div class="container1">
    <div class="container2">
      <div class="float"></div>
      <div class="text1">Text1 </div>
      <div class="text2">Text2 and some other</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

How can I keep the two lines beside the float to not break and not overflow while keeping the container as a flex item?

Comment: Why do you need `float` if you don't want the text to wrap and/or flow under the floated item? What should this look like? And if the text isn't going to break what should happen when the container isn't large enough to hold the contents?

Comment: Perhaps CSS-Grid - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/NWmNMPB

Comment: Just curious if there was a workaround with using floats. But using grid seems like a solution. Thanks anyways